# Not able to execute the test cases in SOAP UI ready API ver 1.7 at the project level. Can someone reply with a solution?

Tags: soapui, ready-api

I am able to execute the test cases using at the test suite and test case level but the execution terminates  at the project level when the run is initiated.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this issue. As it is failing at project level, not at suite or test case level, it means that the problem is at the project level properties and scripts (tear down or set up or event). Please check following things in your project level scripts:

1. Revisit your groovy code once again at project->setup script and project->tear down script, make sure variables are defined outside of conditional loops.
2. Update import statement from `import groovy.sql.*` to `import groovy.sql.sql`